# Conditional Running Total in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

Using VS 2008 Crystal Reports, I would like to do a running total on a formula that is calculated on a group change. When I click on add a running total, this formula does not appear in the Available Tables and Fields list.

This is the logic:

On Change Group of group

```
if CalculatedValue > 0 then
    ReportRunningTotal1 += CalculatedValue  
else
    ReportRunningTotal2 += CalculatedValue
```

Can I specify a condition in a running total? If not, how else could I do this?

More info: I am doing a running total called `GroupRunningTotal` of the value of db field `BillableHours`. At change of group, I am comparing `GroupRunningTotal` to a db field for that group `MaxHours`, and I display a result of `MaxHours - GroupRunningTotal` at the group level.

Appropriate today - Think of it like the electoral college - the person who wins the election does not depend on total number of votes, but of number of votes in the electoral college.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question completely (I don't quite understand you), but yes you can specify a condition for your running total. In the **Edit Running Total Field** menu, play around with the **Evaluate** section.

Comment: I realize I asked the question incorrectly. I would like to do a running total on a formula that is calculated on a group change. When I click on add a running total, this formula does not appear in the Available Tables and Fields list.

Comment: "I am doing a running total called GroupRunningTotal of the value of db field BillableHours. At change of group, I am comparing GroupRunningTotal to a db field for that group MaxHours, and I display a result of MAxHours - GroupRunningTotal at the group level." Do you mean that you **want** to do this but can't, or that you **are** doing this and want to do something else? If the latter, what do you actually want to do?

Comment: @Mark . Currently, in the group header section, I am showing the difference between MaxHours ( a constant based on the group ) and ActualHours. This will be positive or negative. At the end of the report I want to show two totals - number of overhours and number of underhours as shown at the group level. Ie group1: 3 ; group2: -2; group3 :1  . In report footer I want to show Over:4  , under:-2. A running total at the field level would just show: Over:2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely cannot use one RT field as condition for other RT field. You can use formulas, placed on group footer and evaluated 'whileprintingrecords()'; in these formulas you can assign/sum into some variables and display these variables at the end of report. About like next (generic idea only, you need initialization and display routines as well):

```
numbervar rtcurrent := sum({somefield}, {groupfield});
numbervar rtplus;
numbervar rtminus;
if (rtcurrent > 0)
then rtplus := rtplus + rtcurrent
else rtminus := rtminus + rtcurrent;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm interpreting your question to mean that you want to add up all the negative values in one running total (**RT_Neg**) and all the positive values in another (**RT_Pos**).  How about this:

1. Make the **RT_Neg** running total.  Under **Field to Summarize**, sum your {Tbl1}.{Amount}. Under evaluate, enter "{Tbl1}.{Amount}<0" as your custom formula. Never reset.
2. Make the **RT_Pos** running total.  Under **Field to Summarize**, sum your {Tbl1}.{Amount}. Under evaluate, enter "{Tbl1}.{Amount}>0" as your custom formula. Never reset.
3. Insert both running totals in the group footer (if you put them in the header, it may not sum properly)

Alternatively, you can:

1. Make a custom formula "If {Tbl1}.{Amount}<0 then {Tbl1}.{Amount} else 0" and make a running total based off that.

I think one of these 2 options will get you to your goal.